# What should desired tenuring distribution look like?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

After adding `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution` flag to my application server I've noticed quite strange behaviour of tenuring distribution. It often changes threshold. At one moment it sets threshold to 6, and few moments later it sets it to 1. See three distribution examples:

```
4082.199: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4082.199: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 57671680 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:     753160 bytes,     753160 total
- age   2:     827136 bytes,    1580296 total
- age   3:     820224 bytes,    2400520 total
- age   4:   16311440 bytes,   18711960 total
- age   5:    5282008 bytes,   23993968 total
- age   6:    3655960 bytes,   27649928 total
: 945322K->42452K(1013760K), 0.0174052 secs] 3669835K->2766980K(5007360K), 0.0177287 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
4104.567: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4104.567: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 57671680 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 6)
- age   1:   46489056 bytes,   46489056 total
- age   2:     574496 bytes,   47063552 total
- age   3:     821560 bytes,   47885112 total
- age   4:     704848 bytes,   48589960 total
- age   5:   16020184 bytes,   64610144 total
- age   6:    4871920 bytes,   69482064 total
: 943572K->88311K(1013760K), 0.0794895 secs] 3668100K->2816248K(5007360K), 0.0799070 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs]
4107.628: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4107.628: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 57671680 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 6)
- age   1:   68689512 bytes,   68689512 total
- age   2:   11023360 bytes,   79712872 total
- age   3:     574496 bytes,   80287368 total
- age   4:     821560 bytes,   81108928 total
- age   5:     703768 bytes,   81812696 total
: 989431K->103750K(1013760K), 0.2181073 secs] 3717368K->2852056K(5007360K), 0.2184687 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.11, real=0.21 secs]
4110.840: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4110.840: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 57671680 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 6)
- age   1:   64760056 bytes,   64760056 total
: 1004870K->73705K(1013760K), 0.1239617 secs] 3753176K->2834924K(5007360K), 0.1243693 secs] [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.01, real=0.12 secs]
4160.382: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4160.382: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 57671680 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:   47015728 bytes,   47015728 total
: 974825K->47965K(1013760K), 0.0499277 secs] 3736044K->2809308K(5007360K), 0.0504025 secs] [Times: user=0.14 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
4214.500: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4214.500: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 57671680 bytes, new threshold 2 (max 6)
- age   1:   32275144 bytes,   32275144 total
- age   2:   27719512 bytes,   59994656 total
```

Is this behaviour abnormal? I was wondering whether maybe there is some problem with JVM settings. Those are flags I'm using:

`-server -Xms5000m -Xmx5000m -XX:NewSize=1100m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=82 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGC XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamp`

Comment: There is nothing wrong in that, you can configure tenuring distribution byusing -XX: InitialTenuringThreshold, -XX: MaxTenuringThreshold, and -XX: TargetSurvivorRatio flags. More on this https://blog.codecentric.de/2011/08/nutzliche-jvm-flags-teil-5/

Comment: Garbage collection is a means to an end that is supposed to work out of the box most of the time. If your application behaves as expected and CPU/memory usage is fine then there is no need to mess with GC details